# How do I iterate through a many to one field of a model instance?

Tags: python, django

I want to write a model method that modifies it's nested fields

I'm having trouble iterating through an object that is related to the main model. The code in particular is:

```
def set_si_units(self):
    self.currently.get_si_units()
    for i in range(0, self.hourly.data.count()):
        self.hourly.data[i].get_si_units()
```

The 2nd line that modifies `self.currently` runs without a hitch and I receive converted temperatures. The for loop however gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: 'RelatedManager' object does not support indexing
```

I'd really like to be able to iterate through each instance of the `Data` model individually so I can convert the temperatures as I am doing with the `Currently` model.

I've included the relevant code below as well. Please let me know if you need to see something else. Any help or feedback with regards to my approach is greatly appreciated!

**Traceback**

```
File "/path_to_project/project/weather/models.py", line 137, in get_si_units
    self.hourly.data[i] = self.hourly.data[i].get_si_units()
TypeError: 'RelatedManager' object does not support indexing
```

**Classes with get_si_units() (eg. Currently & Data)**

```
class SomeClass(model.Models):
    temperature = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    ... # Other fields

    def convert_f_to_c(self, temperature_f):
        ...

    def get_si_units(self):
        data_point = self
        data_point.temperature = self.convert_f_to_c(self.temperature)
        ... # Convert other fields
        return data_point
```

**Location class that I'm stuck on**

```
class Location(models.Model):
    currently = models.OneToOneField(Currently, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hourly = models.OneToOneField(Hourly, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    def set_si_units(self):
        self.currently.get_si_units()
        for i in range(0, self.hourly.data.count()):
            self.hourly.data[i].get_si_units()
```

Comment: Generally in Python, if you find yourself iterating over `range` of the size of something, you know you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use get all objects then iterate over it.

```
class Location(models.Model):
    currently = models.OneToOneField(Currently, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hourly = models.OneToOneField(Hourly, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    def set_si_units(self):
        self.currently.get_si_units()
        for hourly_data in self.hourly.data.all():
           hourly_data.get_si_units()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried this method before, but `hourly_data` is a local instance and doesn't modify `self`. Is there a way I could do it this way but still get a full `Location` object back?

Comment: If you want to modify the objects just assign the new values thus replacing the old ones

Comment: I must be missing something trivial because I can't figure out how to assign the individual `hourly_data` instances without saving to the database. Could you show me an example?

Comment: You can modify it if there is a property you can use. If there is not then i would suggest you use some serializer and use json data